# cannot borrow `self.blocks` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, substrate

I want to delete the BTreeMap's key and value if the BTreeMap's key Less than a value:

```
fn update_confirmed_height(&mut self, new_confirmed_height: u32) {
    assert!(new_confirmed_height >= self.confirmed_height);
    assert!(new_confirmed_height <= self.current_height);

    for height in self.blocks.keys() {
        if height < &new_confirmed_height {
            self.blocks.remove(&height);
        }
    }
}
```

But `self.blocks.remove(&height)` report an error:
`cannot borrow self.blocks as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this problem as far as I can immediately see. If you're able to use nightly features, you can use the retain method on BTreeMap. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.retain. LATER EDIT: The latest Rust release (1.53.0) has stabilised the retain method in BTreeMap so this can now be used without nightly features. See https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html for more info.

Alternatively, since it appears that your keys are u32, they could be easily copied. Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
    pub fn update_confirmed_height(&mut self, new_confirmed_height: u32) {
        let keys = {
            let mut keys = vec![];
            for (key, _) in self.map.iter() {
                if key < &new_confirmed_height {
                    keys.push(*key);    
                }
            }
            
            keys
        };
        
        for key in keys {
            self.map.remove(&key);
        }
    }
```

Another solution would be to mutate the actual map itself, and create a new map. That will, with this quick version off the top of my head at least, require a clone of the value.

```
    pub fn update_confirmed_height(&mut self, new_confirmed_height: u32) {
        self.blocks = {
            let mut new_blocks = BTreeMap::new();
            for (key, value) in self.blocks.iter() {
                if key < &new_confirmed_height {
                    new_blocks.insert(*key, value.clone());    
                }
            }
            
            new_blocks
        }
    }
```

The important thing, if you ask me, is that understand "why" the compiler was showing that error, and why and how the above solutions work around the problem. Once you do, you may be able to come up with better solutions than the ones above with some time and thought.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions as I know.

1. if you can use nightly version of rust, use [retain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.retain)
2. clone keys and use it in for loop
3. iterate twice. when first iterating, store keys for remove to somewhere and remove these from blocks at second iterating

I wish there is a better solution